# Get Bitmap from Resources

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I have this code to add an item to an ArrayList:

```
    public Questions(int questionMode) {
            getID = new Random();
            allQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();

            allQuestions.add(new Question(2, 0, 0, 2, 5, (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.flag_dutch)), "The Netherlands", true)); //<-- error at this line
        }
```

I've intilize allQuestions in the Constructor of the class, but when I run the code I get a NullPointerException. This is my logcat:

```
12-27 18:14:25.335: E/InputEventReceiver(3583): Exception dispatching input event.
12-27 18:14:25.335: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.obattech.twoplayergame.Questions.createFlagQuestions(Questions.java:80)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.obattech.twoplayergame.Questions.<init>(Questions.java:54)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag.startCountDown(GuessFlag.java:199)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag$1.onTouch(GuessFlag.java:75)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7332)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2115)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1468)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2063)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-27 18:14:25.340: E/MessageQueue-JNI(3583):   at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-27 18:14:25.340: D/AndroidRuntime(3583): Shutting down VM
12-27 18:14:25.340: W/dalvikvm(3583): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x410e72a0)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583): java.lang.NullPointerException
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:81)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.Questions.createFlagQuestions(Questions.java:80)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.Questions.<init>(Questions.java:54)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag.startCountDown(GuessFlag.java:199)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.obattech.twoplayergame.games.GuessFlag$1.onTouch(GuessFlag.java:75)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:7332)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2416)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2117)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2115)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1468)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2487)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2063)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:7520)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3376)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:3308)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:4402)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4380)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4484)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:171)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:125)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:124)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
12-27 18:14:25.350: E/AndroidRuntime(3583):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I think it has something to do with getting a Bitmap from the Resources, but I can't figure out how to fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming `Questions` is your `Activity`, since you use it as the reference for `getResources()`.

That being the case, you cannot put stuff in the constructor (except maybe initialization variables) and expect them to work; the `Activity`'s resources are not ready to be used at this point. Use [`onCreate()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onCreate%28android.os.Bundle%29) instead:

```
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        getID = new Random();
        allQuestions = new ArrayList<Question>();

        allQuestions.add(new Question(2, 0, 0, 2, 5, (BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.flag_dutch)), "The Netherlands", true)); //<-- error at this line
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a NULL Pointer here: Questions.java:80

You need to include this code to really know what the issue is.  This is reported in the StackTrace (just start at the top, and read down, until you see your code referenced).

Comment: The OP knows this, and has put a `//` comment on the line that is causing the issue (namely line 80). I think this answer is better suited to be a comment...